# How to center one grid template column

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I currently have all grid template columns aligning left: however I want ONLY the edit column to align in the center could someone please show me how to do that.

```
.ScheduleGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [id]minmax(0, .9fr) [interval]minmax(0, 1fr) [project-id]minmax(0, 2fr) [database]minmax(0, 5fr)
    [create-timestamp]minmax(0, 2fr) [create-user-id]minmax(0, 1fr) [edit]minmax(0, 2.5fr);
  column-gap: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

select the "edit" div and then use `justify-self: center;` to center it along the column